# What is the benefit of reverse proxy if we can expose to port 80 directly?

Tags: jenkins, proxy, docker

[Installing Jenkins with Docker](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+with+Docker) tells us to EXPOSE to port 49001 then use reverse proxy to expose to port 80. What is the benefit of using reverse proxy why don't just expose to port 80 directly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding a reverse proxy can have several benefits, such as allowing you to scale the number of servers behind the proxy in a transparent way.

That extra abstraction layer has lots of other benefits, such as:

1. security by hiding the technology that lies behind the proxy
2. load balancing
3. caching and compression of what the servers behind the proxy are sending back
4. Many others...